# Sequence number in JSON array for powerbi

Tags: arrays, json, powerbi

I get the below data from the 'World of Tanks' API and would like to show it in Power BI. The challenge is the arrays I get for damage and piercing_power. I would like to show 3 rows from this data with the damage and piercing power next to each other, how would I do that?

```
"4": {
            "nation_i18n": "U.S.S.R.",
            "name": "_76mm_L-11",
            "price_gold": 0,
            "level": 4,
            "damage": [
                110,
                110,
                156
            ],
            "nation": "ussr",
            "rate": 12.27,
            "price_credit": 25990,
            "tanks": [
                1,
                2049
            ],
            "module_id": 4,
            "name_i18n": "76 mm L-11",
            "piercing_power": [
                68,
                75,
                38
            ],
            "turrets": [
                259,
                3,
                3843
            ]
        }
```

Comment: I think your example needs to be wrapped in { } to be valid json.

Answer (score 0):

After converting to a Table and Expanding, I would Add a Column and use the Table.FromColumns function to construct a nested table on each row from the damage and piercing_power list-type columns.  Here's my attempt at that:

`= Table.FromColumns ( { [damage] , [piercing_power] } , { "damage" , "piercing_power" } )`

That table can then be expanded to get your required output.

Here's my full script:

`let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\mikeh\Downloads\WOT.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"nation_i18n", "name", "price_gold", "level", "damage", "nation", "rate", "price_credit", "tanks", "module_id", "name_i18n", "piercing_power", "turrets"}, {"nation_i18n", "name", "price_gold", "level", "damage", "nation", "rate", "price_credit", "tanks", "module_id", "name_i18n", "piercing_power", "turrets"}),
    #"Added MyTable" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Value", "MyTable", each Table.FromColumns ( { [damage] , [piercing_power] } , { "damage" , "piercing_power" } )),
    #"Expanded MyTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added MyTable", "MyTable", {"damage", "piercing_power"}, {"damage.1", "piercing_power.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded MyTable",{{"name", "name.1"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"`

Comment: Thanks Mike, will give this a try as soon as possible. Would the sequence be guaranteed? Especially the sequence of the 2 arrays must match

Comment: Maybe someone from Microsoft could give you a guarantee. All I can say is it worked in my tests.  You should test it also.

Comment: this solution works only with import query connection not with direct query (live connection)..how to do the same in direct query then?